# change resolution of an object formal class RasterLayer sourced from a .tif

Tags: plot, maps, raster, tiff

Hej all,

I am trying to create a rasterLayer object in R from a .tif file.

I am using the raster() function from the raster package. I tried all commands within that function (specifing ncol, nrow, res, ...) but the image I get is always highly pixelated (while the original .tif is very sharp).

Can anyone help me find a way to load the file so that the restult is sharp as well?

THanks for all help!!

[How it should look like (apart from the colours)][1]
[How it looks like][2]

The file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2x58sbjgamkh15f/mammal_richness.tif?dl=0

````
#load data
x <- "./mammal_richness.tif" 
RasterData <- raster(x)

#plot data
worldPlot <- ggplot() +
 geom_raster(data= RasterData, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = mammal_richness))+
 scale_fill_gradient("Mammal richness",
                     low = "grey96", high = "black", na.value = "grey96",
                     guide = guide_colourbar(direction = "horizontal", barwidth = 10, 
                                             title.position = "top"))```


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTG88.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwtZ7.png
````

**EDIT - solution**

It turns out, the RasterData object is fine ( `plot(RasterData)` results in a sharp image).  However, to force ggplot to use the full data available, it is necessary to change the maxpixel argument in the fortify function:

```
RasterData_big <- fortify(RasterData, maxpixels = 1e6)
```

This will take a while, but afterwards the image is nice and sharp.

Comment: did you try `plot(RasterData)`  (and see the maxpixels argument, but you probably don't need that)?

Comment: If I use ```plot(RasterData)``` I get a sharp image. Thanks! So the problem is in the ```geom_raster```command within ggplot2. Any suggestions on how to fix that? Thanks for your help!